# is there an alternative way to access or view my databases on the backend of my joomla website?

Tags: joomla

I'm newbie here in Joomla ..
is there an alternative way(except Joomla Extension Directory and JooDatabase which is not free) to access the phpmyadmin or view my databases without logging in on cpanel provided by my web hosting company?
(sorry for the bad grammar)

Comment: Are you asking the code question of how you would write such an thing?  I think the important question is what functionality are you actually looking for.  Usually phpmyadmin has a url so one thing you can do is to make a custom module in the administrator that contains a link to the url and then just login that way (depending on your host set up).

Answer (score 0):

check this URL, 
http://www.templatemonster.com/help/joomla-3-x-how-to-check-database-details-in-the-admin-panel.html

Follow the above steps and let me know.